# Resizing Android Drawable Item

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, drawable

How do you resize a drawable item? I am trying to modify a png icon for the Android 12 Splash Screen.

This is my themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.SimpleSplashScreen" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/e_espn_logo</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I am trying to resize the drawable in this line:

```
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/e_espn_logo</item>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add a layer-list drawable and use it in your theme:

in splash_logo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:width="your_icon_width"
        android:height="your_icon_height"
        android:drawable="@drawable/e_espn_logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
</layer-list>
```

and then:

```
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_logo</item>
```

Answer (score -1):

create dimensions, or change height and width in drawable code